# How do i initialize an array using an initilializer list delimited by braces " ( { and } ) " in C?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

In my c programming homework I am asked to **initialize an array using an initializer list delimited by braces.** I've googled every thing and I can't find an example of an initializer list delimited by braces. By the way, the array I am initializing is 2-D so if you could format your answer so that it is representative of a 2-D array, that would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: What exactly did you *Google* for? 1st hit for "*array initializer in c*": https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/C_Programming/Arrays.html.

Comment: What other character have you seen for initializer lists?

Comment: @CristiFati So which one is an array list delimited by braces. Because I only see array lists delimited by commas. Could you provide the example that is delimited by "braces"

Comment: @Barmar I typically only see lists delimited by commas

Comment: The individual elements are delimited by commas, but the whole list is delimited by curly braces.

Comment: @Barmar could you please provide an example in the answer section. I'd be glad to gice you a green check mark if u did.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
int a[ 2 ][ 3 ] = { { 5, 6, 7 }, { 10, 20, 30 } };
```